# Packing tree into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, tree-structure, javascript-objects

Ok, so this shouldn't be difficult, however I have encountered weird and bizarra flukes.

I am trying to pack a tree into an array, where each node is something like:

- title: string-for-display
- key: id-value
- children: array of child nodes

the fluke is so strange I can't comprehend it at all: when I try to add a child to a node, I do something like

```
if(node.children == undefined) {
  node.children = new Array();
}

node.children.push({ title: value, key: key });
```

this was deleting some previously inserted nodes....so I did some debugging and found that this code:

```
if(node.children == undefined) {
  node.children = new Array();
}
```

was at fault, which doesn't make any sense at all - node.children = new Array() shouldn't delete ANYTHING if node.children is undefined......, right?

Am I doing something wrong? if so, how do I pack the tree into an array in Javascript?

Comment: This seems entirely unrelated to the problem of storing a tree structure in an array.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are using the `undefined` value is not consistent with Javascript standard practices. I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but try changing you code to

```
if (typeof(node.children) == 'undefined') { 
  node.children = [];
}
```

This might actually help. Also, as you can see, using the Array constructor is unnecessary: `[]` creates a new empty array.

Undefined is not an actual reserved word in Javascript. There is nothing preventing you from setting

```
undefined = 2;
```

after which any comparisons to it will behave unpredictably.

Comment: +1.  OP may not be doing this, but if the code is contained then declaring a variable named undefined should be perfectly fine AFAIK.  So the code could be changed to:  var undefined; if (node.children === undefined) { node.children = []; }.  Of course, this is only useful if you're using the same variable for this purpose in a large body of code.  The string comparison has always rubbed me the wrong way though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `in` operator?

```
if (!("children" in node))
  node.children = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a property exists on an object, use `hasOwnProperty`

```
if (!node.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
    node.children = [];
}
```